# Python code for SW-420 vibration sensor

Tags: python, sensor

I bought an [SW-420 vibration sensor](http://www.elecrow.com/vibration-sensor-module-sw420-p-525.html).

So, I want to make a sensor for touch and vibration detection. This is my first Raspberry Pi project.

I was googling for open source Python code but couldn't find any.

Could you help me if you don't mind?

[image: SW-420 vibration sensor]

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Pay attention to [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error) and please give your question *a clear title.*

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have much experience with Python, or the Raspberry Pi generally, the easiest code I've seen uses the [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.0/) library. There are installation instructions on the [linked homepage.](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.0/)

The recipes page there has a simple [motion detector example](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.0/recipes.html#motion-sensor) that should work with your vibration sensor. ***Whatever you do, don't use their wiring diagram*** as it connects the sensor to 5V. The 5V output from the sensor is likely to damage your Pi. You need to connect your sensor to [3.3V, GND, and GPIO4](http://raspi.tv/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-pinouts.png) to get a 3.3V output:

```py
from gpiozero import MotionSensor, LED 
from signal import pause

pir = MotionSensor(4) led = LED(16)

pir.when_motion = led.on 
pir.when_no_motion = led.off

pause()
```

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet of the sensor says ir has a digital output , so i'm assuming you need to detect digital output frecuency , I made a quick class on python that detects more than 1000 interrupts on a second , it turns on an LED (conected to another pin of raspberry pi ) you can modify it to change the frecuency you need

it should be something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import math as m 

class Sw40(object):
    """docstring for Senal"""
    def __init__(self, pin , led):
        self.led = led
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(self.led,GPIO.OUT)
        self.pin = pin
        GPIO.setup(self.pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

        GPIO.add_event_detect(self.pin, GPIO.RISING, callback=self.callback, bouncetime=1)
        self.count = 0 

    def callback(self , pin):
        self.count += 1

    def LedOn(self):
        GPIO.output(self.led , 1)

    def LedOff(self):
        GPIO.output(self.led , 0)








def main():
    sensor = Sw40(21,20) 
    try:
        while True:

            time.sleep(1)
            if sensor.count >=1000:
                sensor.LedOn()
            else:
                sensor.LedOff()
            sensor.count = 0        



    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

running this code as copy-paste , the led will turn on if there is more than 1000 interrupts on a second , you just need to instantiate the class with the pins you connect the LED and the sensor to your raspberry , on the example (main function) The signal should be connected to Broadcom pin #21 , and the LED to Broadcom (BCM) pin #20

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Nothing fancy needed here ( digital out means the output is ether high or low ). You just need the Pi to detect when the sensor's output goes high. This can be done using a Python script. I suggest you go to https://www.raspberrypi.org/ to learn how to do this. It isn't hard even for someone without programing experience.

Comment: The raspberrypi.org site is kind of unintuitive these days. It's quite difficult to find specific pieces of technical information without encountering [burping jelly babies](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/burping-jelly-baby/) and [flappy astronauts](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/flappy-astronaut/). Can you point to a specific tutorial that might be helpful?